# ARMA zero coefficients (not statistically significant)

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, arima, model-selection, regression-coefficients

I seem to have forgotten what to do when the coefficients of the time series model are not statistically significant like $\phi_2$, $\phi_3$, $\phi_4$ below. A university course taught us to set each non-significant coefficient to 0 until they are all significant. I've done this by removing the coefficient with highest p-value and I ended up with $\phi_2$ and $\phi_4$ being 0. However, technically I am fitting an ARFIMA model and I'm not sure if this approach still works when fractional differencing is also present.

The ACF decays slowly and the PACF cuts off at lag 4 suggesting an AR(4) component. Furthermore, the AIC is lowest for ARFIMA(4,d,0). However, setting not statistically significant coefficients to zero I end up with a model which has an AR(3) component. The table below shows the fit of ARFIMA(4,d,0) with d.f. being the fractional difference $d$.

[image]

So I don't know if what I've done is correct: I calculated a bunch of ARFIMA(p,d,q) models and selected the (p,q) such that the AIC is lowest. This turned out to be ARFIMA(4,d,0). This fitted with the PACF cutting off at lag 4. Upon fitting, the fit suggests the coefficients are zero as above.